# Probability transformation using R

Tags: r, transformation, probability, normal-distribution, weibull

I want to turn a continuous random variable `X` with `cdf` `F(x)` into a continuous random variable `Y` with `cdf` `F(y)` and am wondering how to implement it in R.

For example, perform a probability transformation on data following normal distribution (X) to make it conform to a desirable Weibull distribution (Y).

(x=0 has CDF F(x=0)=0.5, CDF F(y)=0.5 corresponds to y=5, then x=0 corresponds to y=5 etc.)

Comment: Most people here would probably look more favorably on your question if your post demonstrated some prior effort at programming a solution.

Comment: I think perhaps this should go on cross-validated rather than stack overflow?

Answer (score 7):

There are many built in distribution functions, those starting with a 'p' will transform to a uniform and those starting with a 'q' will transform from a uniform.  So the transform in your example can be done by:

```
y <- qweibull( pnorm( x ), 2, 6.0056 )
```

Then just change the functions and/or parameters for other cases.

The distr package may also be of interest for additional capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can transform an observation x on X to an observation y on Y by

- getting the probability of X≤x, i.e. F<sub>X</sub>(x).
- then determining what observation y has the same probability,

I.e. you want the probability Y≤y = F<sub>Y</sub>(y) to be the same as F<sub>X</sub>(x).

This gives F<sub>Y</sub>(y) = F<sub>X</sub>(x).

Therefore y = F<sub>Y</sub><sup>-1</sup>(F<sub>X</sub>(x))

where F<sub>Y</sub><sup>-1</sup> is better known as the quantile function, Q<sub>Y</sub>. The overall transformation from X to Y is summarized as: Y = Q<sub>Y</sub>(F<sub>X</sub>(X)).

In your particular example, from the R help, the distribution functions for the normal distribution is `pnorm` and the quantile function for the Weibull distribution is `qweibull`, so you want to first of all call `pnorm`, then `qweibull` on the result.